# selenium firefox wait for high traffic website

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to log into a website which is down for most of the day. Due to high traffic, the login page is not loading or loading very slow therefore most of the times it fails.

1) What command should I execute on selenium IDE 2.9.1 to wait for a page to load completely (because it's slow it should wait for about 50 secs after opening the page) and then check if the page is the actual login page or the error page.

2) If that's the login page, proceed with the login otherwise repeat until the login page is loaded.

3) After the login, we also might get some errors, so again it should check the content of the page received and see if that's the actual logged in page.

Comment: Have you looked into setTimeout? There you can change the amount of time you'll wait for the page to load. Honestly it sounds like you're testing against production: maybe you should try a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to achieve with below points.

1. Please refer [setSpeed & setTimeout](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/03/use-of-setspeed-and-settimeout-commands.html) to know what exactly fits you. You may need to use them for your testing.
2. You need to add the user extension java script into your Selenium IDE. Java script can be found [here](https://github.com/73rhodes/sideflow/blob/master/sideflow.js).
3. This user extension supports for `gotoIf` function as explained in [51_Elliot_Blog](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html). This function can go to Label based on the condition.
4. Refer IDE Script [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWSZm.jpg). It never finishes until it find element.

You can implement these logic so that script keeps run until log page displays and/or until logged successfully.